# Hex, curse, spell, jinx, charm

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm listening to some Harry Potter audio books, and there are so many words describing the work of the spell. One can be *cursed*, *charmed*, *hexed* or *jinxed*. What's the difference?

Comment: Close voters: This is a nine-year-old question. It has been viewed 7,000 times, and it has drawn several reasonably useful answers. Can't we just leave it alone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the etymologies from most recent words to older (from etymonline.com). I recommend reading them as these words these days might have lost much of their delineation - today we label them under one category and often use them interchangeably.

> **jinx (n.)** 
>       1911, Amer.Eng., from 17c. *jyng* "a charm, a spell," originally "wryneck," a bird used in witchcraft and divination, from L. *iynx* "wryneck," from Gk. *iynx*. The verb is 1917 in Amer.Eng., from the noun. Related: Jinxed; jinxing.
>
> **hex (v.)** 
>       1830, Amer.Eng., from Pennsylvania German hexe "to practice witchcraft," from Ger. *hexen* "to hex," related to *Hexe* "witch," from M.H.G. *hecse*, *hexse*, from O.H.G. *hagazussa* (see hag). Noun meaning "magic spell" is first recorded 1909; earlier it meant "a witch" (1856).
>
> **charm (v.)** 
>       c.1300, "to recite or cast a magic spell," from O.Fr. *charmer*, from L.L. *carminare*, from L. *carmen* (see charm (n.)). Related: Charmed; charming.
>
> **curse (n.)** 
>       late O.E. *curs* "a prayer that evil or harm befall one," of uncertain origin, perhaps from O.Fr. *curuz* "anger," or L. *cursus* "course." Connection with cross is unlikely. No similar word exists in Germanic, Romance, or Celtic. The verb is O.E. *cursian*; meaning "to swear profanely" is from early 13c. Related: Cursed; cursing. Curses as a histrionic exclamation is from 1885. The curse "menstruation" is from 1930. Curse of Scotland, the 9 of diamonds in cards, is attested from 1791, but the origin is obscure.

In the actual meaning and use, they can all be used as verbs.

*Jinx*, *hex* and *curse* can have exactly the same meaning and it is negative; while *charm* is ambiguous: it can refer to both positive and negative.

The older words *curse* and *charm* have developed other, common meanings, to *swear* and to *attract*, respectively, while the younger words have only meanings related to magic and mysticism.

Comment: Can you please specify the source of the information?

Comment: *Charm* can also be used like *glamour*, which is what the fey population uses to change their appearance. It is often negative in this sense, since the outward appearance is usually intended to trick people.

Comment: @Kit, you are right, of course, and I have edited the answer to reflect this. I would still say that it is significant that it is the only one of the above that can be used as positive.

Comment: Amish *"hex signs",* in Pennsylvania, were believed by non-Amish to be good luck charms. (They are actually just decorations; see [here](http://www.amishnews.com/featurearticles/storyofhexsigns.htm).) So the word *hex* is sometimes used for good luck magic. *Jinx* and *curse* are both always negative, as far as I know.

Comment: @Peter, I see. I learn from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_sign#Controversy that etymology is not clear - it *might* be from *hex* - six, not from *hex* - hag - witch

Comment: @Unreason: I don't believe it's from *six*; I suspect that's a case of political correctness gone amok.

Comment: @Unreason I agree that charm is the most positive of the four.

Answer (score 13):

Two points about HP as a source of English words: as a work of fiction, it has its own rules.  For example, 'Charms' is a separate subject at Hogwarts, and the Basilisk is a large snake: neither applies (necessarily) in other contexts.  And because it is set in a 'magic-heavy' environment, the author had to find different words for spells and casting them, in the same way that an English teacher encourages students to use different words for 'said'.

I am not sure that there is in fact any difference in the words when referring to spells; the witches in *Macbeth* say "Now the charm's wound up", which is certainly not a positive reference.  But really the only person who can give a clear answer would be a witch or wizard...

Edit to expand on the last sentence: there is no 'correct' answer, any more than there is to 'What colour is a unicorn?'  You can quote books and folklore, but ultimately the only sensible response is 'whatever was in the mind of the person imagining it'.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that HP is specific in use of words; *charm* can be both positive and negative - it certainly differs in that sense.

Comment: +1 for "what colour is a unicorn?"

Comment: Pfft, what color is a unicorn indeed! I'm pink. Can't you see me? :)

Comment: Yes. If you read other fantasy fiction, they will have come up with other completely different meanings for those words in their "universe". For comparison, in Kim Harrison's Rachel Morgan series, a "charm" is magic that requires a lot of prep work ahead of time, a hex is magic that draws on a ley-line for power, and a curse is demon magic.

Answer (score 3):

For more nuance:

- a person casts a **hex** on another person or an object in order to make them (or it) do something, or to limit them in some manner (a hex to make someone keep their mouth shut or to make a stone fly). This is usually in a negative sense.
- a person casts a **charm** to affect the properties of something or someone (to make someone love someone else, or to keep a door from closing. This can be negative or positive. It is closely related to a hex, possibly a hypernym (a superset concept). Both a hex and a charm are somewhat temporary in nature.
- a **curse** is a debilitating pronouncement. You break in to King Tut's tomb, you might be cursed to die of dysentery (a pronouncement that was promised to occur on some violation of a condition rather than it just happens no matter what).
- a **jinx**, well in modern AmE, it seems only to be used as a reflection that a stigma has been placed *inadvertently* somehow (not on purpose), by mentioning a bad occurrence word one is jinxing a situation leading the bad alternative more likely to happen ('knocking on wood' helps dispel a possible jinx). The most common usage is when you repeat the same word at exactly the same time as someone else, one of them gets to 'jinx' the other into silence (the other is not allowed to speak until allowed by the first).

This taxonomy/ontology of magical incantations is somewhat problematic, similar in nature to an ontology of ESP powers, in that it is an ontology mostly of psychological artifacts rather than testable physical phenomena.

Comment: I'm sure people say "That computer's jinxed: get another one.", and have done since WW2, when they referred to cars or aircraft (a bit like "it's got a *gremlin*")

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,

**Charm** mean a spell that affects the way the charmed person is, often psychologically, but in a intrinsic way.

**Curse** (as a spell) mean a spell that affects what would happen to the cursed person in some future or any time he does certain action.

**Hex** is a spell, but the type of spells only witches can cast. And I make a difference between wizard and witch. Often a wizard is seen as a person who uses or practices magic that derives from supernatural or occult source, while a witch has certain tendency to evil. That is because witch is a word instaured by the church (should get a citation somewhere).

**Jinx** is related to a type of curse placed on a person that makes them prey to many minor misfortunes and other forms of bad luck.

If I have time I'll edit this with some citations.

Comment: Terry Pretchett has some decent witches, as far as the genre goes, and they are more often good than bad.

Comment: but that is characteristic of Terry but not from Rowling or classic fantasy as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Here's clear differences:

Cursed - to say bad things about someone in his absence, bad things you want to see happening to him/her. You probably do this in some dark corner calling dark spirits to carry out the evil you're saying.

Charmed - is to say all the good things one wanna hear but in the process capturing his/her mind, taking control of her decisions and before she knows it she's lured into your web.

Hexed or jinxed - is when you use physical muti to hypnotize or take control of someone's phsych or actions so they do whatever you want. You pour something in their food or drink and hypnotize them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Sources which support your statements are always nice. :)