# One word for witches and wizards

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for witches and wizards both, regardless of gender?

Edit 1: Is there a single word for the category of people who do magic (like witches, wizards, warlocks, sorcerers, etc.)?

Edit 2: The usage example comes from a story I made up for my niece. She wanted to know why I was designating male cats who do magic as witches alongside the female cats. Shouldn't they be called wizards, she asked. I then wondered whether there's one word that encompasses everyone who does magic.

Comment: Those both work for both genders.

Comment: @tchrist, would you differentiate between them based on the _type_ of magic then, perhaps, or can they always be used interchangeably?

Comment: In common use (not referencing a dictionary) a warlock is a male witch.  Witches and warlocks use black (evil) magic,while wizards (generally male) are not necessarily evil.  Sorcerers are somewhere in-between.  But many who are "into" this will have much more specific definitions (and will violently object to mine).

Comment: This is all madey-uppy stuff, so you are welcome to make up anything you please. I can cite innumerable works of fiction in which both occur in either gender.

Comment: "Sorceress", of course, is a female sorcerer, although "sorcerer" may be applied to the female sex.

Comment: For example: [witch](http://dragaera.wikia.com/wiki/Witch), [wizard](http://dragaera.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard), [sorcery](http://dragaera.wikia.com/wiki/Sorcery). Again, just make something up: everybody does.

Comment: @tchrist, thank you for your comments. If there isn't a single word that already exists and that you're aware of, that's fine of course. You can say that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering why someone would have voted to close this question. Is it not clear what I'm asking?

Comment: OED for *witch*: “A man who practises witchcraft or magic; a magician, sorcerer, wizard.” and “A female magician, sorceress; in later use esp. a woman supposed to have dealings with the devil or evil spirits and to be able by their co-operation to perform supernatural acts.” And for magician: “One skilled in magic or sorcery; a necromancer, wizard. Also *occas.* a practitioner of legerdemain, a conjuror.” If you want Dungeons and Dragons words, there’s where you should look.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm a little confused. To be clear, are you saying I should delete this question because if I want "Dungeons and Dragons words," I should look in the dictionary and not ask here whether a single word exists that encompasses the definitions of all these words?

Comment: @Tragicomic I did not understand what you were asking for. The general term for a user of magic is of course a *magic-user* or a *magician*, the former being the term using in D&D. But because these are complete fabulations, you can make up anything you want, and it will vary between mythologies. In the real world, such would-be occult practitioners are all *charlatans*, although not all charlatans claim to have magical powers.

Comment: @tchrist: :-) For some reason, the words _magician_ and _conjurer_ bring to mind people on stage performing illusions, rather than someone who is (or is thought to be) a witch or a wizard.

Comment: For those who believe in magic powers, there are distinctions; for example, an Inuit *angekkok* 'summons spirits from the vasty deep', and the word is properly translated as *conjuror* rather than the spellcasting *sorceror*. In a role-playing game, the terms for magic-users are defined by the game, just as a fiction writer can define his own words and worlds.  In normal English, magic does not exist outside stage performances, so there are either no words to describe it, or as many as you want.

Comment: I think the fact that some things don't really exist outside our imagination doesn't mean the words we have for them aren't real. For example, I'm pretty certain Martians and Venusians don't really exist, but we have very real words for them. And Martians and Venusians both could be categorized as aliens. Similarly the words "poltergeist" and "wraith" are real, and both poltergeists and wraiths can be categorized as ghosts. I wonder if there is a similar recognized category for witches and wizards.

Comment: (Sorry my previous comment wasn't clear enough). The point about non-existence is that it destroys categories. A *poltergeist* and a *wraith* may both be ghosts, but what is the difference between them? Your definition is precisely as good as mine, or as that of the *Malleus Maleficarum* if it has one. See also [Hex, spell, jinx, charm?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32048/8019).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using either [Mage or Magus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(fantasy)) (plural: Mages and Magi respectively). Both of them convey a gender-neutral magic-user, without giving off a sense of being a mere illusionist.

> However, the term "mage" has fallen out of use, with wizard and witch
>   being the standard terms for any magic user. The term "mage" is gender
>   neutral.

I'd consider Mage the more neutral option of the two, as Magus has a slight hint of masculinity from Latin.

Comment: I was just wondering if a feminine form "maga" was ever used in Latin to refer to a female mage... I haven't found out yet. BTW the usual pronunciations of "magus" and "magi" in English are "MAY-guss" and "MAY-jye" respectively. I thought I'd mention it because it's a little tricky, like "locus" and "loci."

Comment: *Witch* is from Old English and *wizard* from Late Middle English, but *mage* is not that old. It is, however, “archaic” per the OED.  *Mage* was merely an Early Modern English anglicization of the Latin *magus*; the OED gives only a single Late Middle English citation for *magis*. It was kept hobbling along by the nineteenth century Romantic poets, a tradition carried into the early twentieth century by certain writers of genre fiction who wished to impart an archaizing flavor to their tales. It was later popularized by Gary Gygax, whence it disseminated to paper-and-pencil FRPG gamers.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. And welcome to ELU Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Your edit includes what would have been my first choice (sorcerer) (but then again sorceress does exist, as mentioned elsewhere).

With all that in mind, I'll suggest [conjurer/or](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conjurer):

"a person who conjures  spirits or practices magic; magician"

(Dictionary reference)

Comment: +1 I believe you're right. However, to my mind, "conjurer" brings to mind an image of a man standing on stage cruelly pulling a rabbit out of a hat. So does "magician," for some reason. Not someone who is (or is thought to be) a "witch" or a "wizard." :-(.

Comment: @Tragicomic - You need to keep in mind that none of this (except a stage magician's prestidigitation) is real.  Therefore it's hard to come up with definitions that are well-defined with crisp borders.

Answer (score 2):

The best word for what you're looking for in my opinion is *mage*, because it has the same root word as magic, it's gender neutral, and it just means magic-user and nothing else. But you're not going to get much mileage out of the word mage outside of a fantasy context.

Comment: Plural would be mages/magi. And yes its a bit too arcane for common talk.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I like _mage_, which simply means "magician" as you say, without the connotation of an illusionist on stage (which I feel the words "magician" and "conjurer" carry).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "[practitioner](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/practitioner)". If you want to be specific, you can use the two-word "magical practitioner".

> someone who regularly does a particular activity

Even without "magical", it has a usage within certain literary circles. In the popular novel series *The Dresden Files*, persons who use magic, regardless of the type, are referred to as "[practitioners](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Practitioner#Practitioners)":

> Practitioner is a generic term for an individual who can use magic. The word signifies only the presence of magical talent; it has no connotations regarding the individual's power or skill. There are a number of other terms, however, which do have such connotations.

Obviously, this is used within a specific literary world in this case, but the terminology appears even in other articles:

"[Magician (paranormal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_%28paranormal%29)"

> A magician is a *practitioner* of magic who attains objectives or acquires knowledge using supernatural means.

[The Smart Witch: Introduction to Magic](http://www.thesmartwitch.com/The_Smart_Witch_Magic_Intro.html):

> One thing magical practitioners have in common throughout history and around the world today is curiosity – the quest for knowledge. We are the original inquiring minds who want to know. There is a reason that so many of the first books printed were grimoires – books of magic – on the whole, magical practitioners are great readers.

The major issue as I see it is that the terminology varies depending on the world you're in.

In *Harry Potter*, for example, witch is the feminine version of wizard... the type of magic they do is pretty much identical.

In other worlds, everyone who practices "wizardry", regardless of gender is a "wizard" and the practice of witchcraft is very different, and everyone who practices it is called a "witch", again, regardless of gender, though most seem to be female. Similarly, a "magician" could be something different entirely.

I believe that "practitioner" or "magical practitioner" is a word that holds none of the connotations of the individual words have.

Comment: If I saw the word _practitioner_ used without any qualifiers, I would immediately assume it meant a doctor—a medical practitioner.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet even if it was in a paper **about** magical people? Presumably there's going to be some **context**... and that's also why I recommended the two-word option.

Comment: I’ve never seen or heard _practitioner_ used to refer to, erm, non-Muggles, so I think I’d just be a bit nonplussed if I saw it used, unqualified, in a paper about magical people—I’d first wonder if I’d missed some reference to the medical profession, and then probably suss it out after a batted eyelid or two. _Magical practitioner_ would probably strike me at the first read as a slightly unusual phrasing, but I would at least know immediately what was meant and would probably be used to it by the second reading.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't understand what you want me to say... I've shown that the word is used in magical situations and it seems that your personal dislike is all you're expressing. If you dislike it, then don't vote it up.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. I do believe I have heard the term "practitioners of magic" used.

Answer (score 1):

"Witch" is not necessarily the cognate of "wizard" in any way. A wizard is someone who has developed some form of wisdom (wiz-dom). It comes from Olde English, as the root is "wis", meaning wise. The conversion of that into a personal noun by adding suffix -ard came later as noted below. Its use even then reflected at first and primarily the quality of wisdom as attributed to a person. It has *come to mean* someone, particularly a male, who has developed magical powers.When and how this happened I don't know.

A witch, on the other hand, originates in Olde English as well, and had both male and female forms, and implied a person who had magical power and this was its explicit meaning. It specifically meant someone with the power to bewitch others, usually of the opposite sex.  The human equivalent of a demon of seduction, basically.

Male witches were called "wicca" and females "wicce", and the verb was "wiccian". If you pronounce the c's correctly, it sounds like a tch. So "witchah" and "witcheh".  And if someone is "wiccian" you, they are "witchian" you, or "witchin" you. You are "bewitched".

In fact, witches were thought to be more conversant with spirits, and were thought even to have had congress, even sexual congress, with spirits. But perhaps it was more correct to have thought of them as Celtic shamans and shamanesses, and oracles later to have developed into institutionalized priesthoods, mostly Druidic.

So "witch" is far more magical in origin than "wizard", but wizardry has somehow come to be conflated with a notion of possession of magical power.

Magicians, being of a group called "Magians" and referred to as "Magi", were actually a sect of witch/wizards from the ancient Iranian plateau. The costumery often associated with "wizards" comes from that origin, and is reminiscent of a Scythian Magus, perhaps. They were scholars and mystagogues, and priests, not necessarily in that order.

Perhaps it was they, or rather Greek and later European interpretations of them as iconography for their own purposes which transformed "wizard" into something looking like a Persian Magus (or Mage, Magian, or Magician).

So in the end, for purposes of modern (not necessarily RPG/Fantasy Fiction) uses, we could say that witches represent a kind of innate magic with a propensity to charm or fascinate, wizards represent a profound intellect which is often the confluence of intelligence, intuition, experience, and discipline, whereas someone who managed to combine natural magical power with human mental adroitness would be some sort of psychospiritual renaissance being, a magician of sorts.

John Dee and Isaac Newton represent magicians in this sense, and are the modern representation of true Magi (in English terms). Zoroaster would have been a true Magus in his day, although the destruction of the libraries of Persepolis obscure what that would mean in detail, along with the rest of that tradition. Indeed, for all we know, much work was done there which is the forebear of modern science. Hard to be sure. But that's an aside.

Modern witches, in effect, would be female entertainers, and male entertainers, in any line of work or influences, using charm, often accentuated and augmented by psychotronics and other powerful technology. They're all over the place. Wizards are the deeper scientific and Machiavellian minds, working as either modern viziers, or ministers, giving tyrants advice, or in the former case, giving methods and technology to implement such advice. You have think tanks, councils, foundations, centers, and other "round table groups" just full of wizards and witches, acting as viziers for the ruling elite. Perhaps you have some evil magicians working in those folds as well, such as psychological operations officers high up in the intelligence communities, scientists studying dark technological and scientific frontiers in psychical and paranormal, and extradimensional topics.

You have good witches, good wizards, and good magi as well, but they are sprinkled around sparsely, outside the annals of worldly power, being kind to children and devoting themselves to their crafts, refusing to be corrupted.

Comment: In general, there's no clear dividing line between what a word "is" and what it has "come to mean"; this claim is often referred to as the "etymological fallacy." But for the purposes of world-building, your distinctions seem pretty good to me. The original poster might want to make up different distinctions, and that's also fine.

Comment: *Wizard* is not from Old English as you would incorrectly portray it (and do please note spelling; “olde English” is wrong: the language of *Beowulf* is called **Old English**) but rather from Late Middle English, the very last period before the Early Modern English of Elizabethan England. You can tell because its *wise* component (seen also in *wisdom*) is nearly in its full modern form already.  (Its  *-ard*  ending is a common albeit no longer productive combining form as seen in *coward, drunkard, dastard, bastard, dullard*, and many others.)

Comment: Yes, I should have capitalized olde.

Comment: @AfshinNejat, thank you for the interesting answer.